# If I install a python package with `apt-get`, can I upgrade it later with `pip`?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip

I installed a python package (django) using `sudo apt-get install python-django`. Now I want to upgrade to the latest version.

Should I run `sudo pip install -U django`, or should I uninstall first the `python-django` installed with `apt-get`?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install python-django` installs `django` in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` while `sudo pip install -U django` installs `django` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. This means you cannot upgrade Django installed by APT using pip and vice versa.

The latest version of `django` is unlikely to be provided by the official Ubuntu repositories. Therefore, I would suggest you uninstall the `django` that is installed using `apt-get` and then either use `pip install --user django` to install `django` locally or use virtual environments such as `virtualenv` to manage your Python dependencies. I would discourage you from using `sudo pip install django` because it is a security risk to use `sudo` to install arbitrary Python packages from PyPI which does not check for malicious packages; you can read more about this from an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/15003) I wrote regarding this issue.