# Is `sudo pip install` still a broken practice?

Tags: package-management, permissions, python, pip

I'm new to Ubuntu, so please bear with me. I installed `pip` using this command: `sudo apt-get -y install python-pip`. Then I installed [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) using the command on their website, which was: `sudo pip install -U nltk`. But then I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33004920) that says that everything I did was a "broken practice". The line that struck me the most was that using `sudo pip` is inherently wrong and that giving `pip` too much force could damage operating system files. Can anyone validate this claim?

Note - I only used `sudo` because when I tried the command `apt-get -y install python-pip` it gave me 2 errors:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: *Instructions telling `sudo pip install` are inherently wrong.* – from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33004920/95735

Comment: Sorry, `sudo pip install` is as bad as `curl "some-url" | sudo bash` installs. Similarly, we've had a few times where some developer used `sudo pip install` to install some dependency on their workstation, then checked in broken code to the repo because the `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` file was missing whatever they installed, and everyone else got to figure out what dependency was needed while the guy was on vacation.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Both `sudo pip install` and its other common variant `sudo -H pip install` should **not** be encouraged because it is a security risk to use root privileges to use `pip` to install Python packages from PyPI (Python Package Index).

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056000/486919 (emphasis mine):

> When you run `pip` with `sudo`, you run `setup.py` with `sudo`. In
>   other words, you run arbitrary Python  code from the Internet as root.
>   **If someone puts up a malicious project on PyPI and you install it, you**
>   **give an attacker root access to your machine.** Prior to some recent
>   fixes to `pip` and PyPI, an attacker could also run a man in the
>   middle attack to inject their code when you download a trustworthy
>   project.

As mentioned at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/79327/8761, it is important to note that **anyone** can upload Python packages, including malicious ones, to PyPI.

In short, in accordance with the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), don't use `sudo` with `pip` to install Python packages from PyPI unless you absolutely need to. Instead, consider using `pip install --user` (note that `pip install` with no `sudo` nor additional flags/options defaults to `pip install --user` on Ubuntu currently) or virtual environments (such as `virtualenv`). If you see people recommending `sudo pip` or `sudo -H pip`, please tell them not to.

Comment: If I have used it in the past, how do I clean up what it did?

Comment: So these instructions are wrong? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Comment: @endolith you may sudo the pip uninstall to undo. Also, though, if the package is from a trusted maintainer, such as tensorflow, numpy, etc, the "aye! security!" argument doesn't really make sense. (Also if you install any malicious package, even as "--user", you're basically screwed anyway. The real rule should be: Don't install code from unknown/untrusted people...except in a container--but even then, not recommended.)

Comment: @endolith Those instructions don't say to use sudo.  Maybe they used to and they've seen the error of their ways? :)

Comment: @DavidGardner I guess?  Directions were this: http://web.archive.org/web/20180828233036/https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#2_install_tensorflow_on_system

Comment: `sudo pip install` can uninstall "old" system-installed Python packages, which can make upgrading or uninstalling those OS packages difficult. `sudo pip uninstall` doesn't help here, because it removes the new package but doesn't restore the files from the old one. (My colleague R. Zagar goes into more detail in another answer.)

Comment: @MikeDeSimone If you would like to, feel free to suggest an edit to my answer and add a link to your colleague's answer.

Comment: @edwinksl I'm not sure how to link to another answer on this page.

Answer (score 27):

You must use `sudo` to install pip ***with apt*** (`sudo apt install python-pip`), but as stated in [edwinksl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/442404) you should not use `sudo` to install packages ***with pip***, you should use `pip install --user <package>` to install only for your user, or use a [virtualenv](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvsMyF_cDRAhVI34MKHV8MDMIQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python-guide.org%2Fen%2Flatest%2Fdev%2Fvirtualenvs%2F&usg=AFQjCNEvupNSRAVxfumkI5JFoxABd0GHhQ&bvm=bv.144224172,d.amc) to even further restrict the scope of the package.

Apt installs packages from Ubuntu's repositories, whereas pip installs user-uploaded packages from PyPi which could be malicious.

Answer (score 9):

And for a more tempered reply:

1. You indeed do always have to `sudo apt-get install ...`, that's just how the tool was designed to work.
2. Using `sudo [-H]` with `pip install` is both possible & optional, depending on what exactly you want to do (and hence, "controversy").

One of [Python's mottos](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."* And like most mottos, it's broken with sardonic glee  seemingly at every possible opportunity. (That's why mottos exist, I guess.) Unfortunately, in my most humble opinion, the Python ecosystem consists of many *conflicting* "hard & fast" rules, never to be broken...except for when "yada yada yada" (devil, details, etc).  In almost all cases, this is due to historical evolution of the language & tools (and who wants/needs a history lesson when they just want to get on with their job) -- but also can be due to differences in Mac/Win/*Nix platforms (e.g., Unix/Linux has a similar mentality, but has the advantage of decades more maturity.) So *please* do take all these *"broken practice"* & *"inherently wrong"* cargo-cultists with a huge pinch of salt. Some actually do mean well. (Others are just, well, mean.)

First of all, rather than basic "per-user installs", you'll almost always prefer a virtualenv, because really, that's probably what you'll end up needing. So you might as well start with it now. *How* this is done, exactly, "depends" (see Python motto, above). If you're using Conda (mostly for Mac & Windows), it'll be set up [using Conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). If using "pure" Python *[sic]*, it depends on which version & what python utils you have, but [virtualenvwrapper](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is pretty handy.

Second, just as a counter-example to the "never sudo" rule, you may prefer to `sudo -H pip install -U numpy`, which is perfectly fine, even advantageous, in that it can allow one to avoid downloading/reinstalling/maintaining big libraries, where you only want/need one version, into every virtualenv separately. Big, popular frameworks like scikit-learn, NumPy, matplotlib, SciPy, pandas, etc., can be installed once & done and [re-used across environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option). Further, your local friendly sys-admin might be able to get these installed for *every* user on a system -- and obviously they'd be doing this via `sudo`, as well, e.g., for more complicated installations, such as TensorFlow.

And, lastly, if you are installing some random 3rd party library that does such-and-such (Twitter API, text munging, code formatting, etc), then I totally agree -- don't install it as root via sudo. Sure, install it as your current user. But just remember, [your *user* account has all your really important stuff](https://xkcd.com/1200/).

Comment: Where "tempered" = "counterproductive hand-wringing faffing inviting confusion for the sake of trying not to hurt anyone's feelings". Just be clear and explicit to avoid confusion: there is never any need to do this as a baseline, including your examples. Unix is indeed "roll your own config and risks", it's literally a C mindset, but like there, don't use `malloc` where you don't need to. The `--user` flag does what the OP was asking for and requires no special permissions. You're undermining your good points about _virtualenv_ in the process... nothing "cargo-cultist" about any of this.

Comment: I did already include this perspective in my survey of common responses & opinions (if one reads closely).

Comment: Excellent, very wise comment (albeit a bit long, but that was sort of necessary).

I am discovering, the hard way, the lack of consistency between what I did in the past on my Debian (Devuan now) system (about 10 years old), with many `pip install` done as root (no sudo, thanks), also `pip3 install` done as user or root...

What a mess.

Answer (score 4):

Using "sudo pip install" can and will overwrite python content provided by your OS vendor.  When that happens, any vendor packages affected by this will not pass an "rpm --verify" and your packages will appear to be corrupted.

Do you want to use system-administration tools that your OS vendor has *tested*, or is it okay to use untested components you downloaded from the internet?

When, not if, a malicious package gets uploaded to PyPI... people who use "sudo pip install" will end up running that malicious payload with full system privileges.  Do you want that? (#principleofleastprivilege)

If it's just your laptop, and you're only risking a few cat pictures, then the risk is probably low... but if it's a multi-user system, then the risk is now multiplied by N.  If you have data on the system that has value, or system availability or reliability have value, then the risks also go up.

Please feel free to choose your own adventure, but please get the informed consent of the other users that could be affected by your choice.  They may not be comfortable with the same level of risk as you.

Answer (score 1):

To add to these answers: I do not know about Ubuntu, but on Fedora I am able to use `sudo dnf install python3-numpy` format to install **MANY** packages useful to me. This does not have the disadvantage of being insecure (distro repo maintainer has validated packages), but also allows you to install system-wide. Only drawback is that the distro repo versions may be slightly lagging the packages in PyPI.

Answer (score -5):

No, this is correct. I cannot validate this claim. I always use `sudo -H` with `pip`. `pip` can only damage operating system files as much as `apt`. Only do not use `sudo` with `pip` when you want to install only for that user.

Comment: On your personal computer, when do you need to install `pip` system-wide?
If you're a sysadmin, maybe that's a different story.

Comment: The apt command and your apt packages are designed, secured, signed and deployed as a coordinated suite specific to your OS.  Pip packages are designed for a different ecosystem, and very well may break your OS, or even be malicious trojans which can't be trusted since they aren't signed by the OS vendor.