# What are the differences/similarities between multiple python package management?

Tags: package-management, python

Python seems to have multiple package management system that leads to confusions and conflicts when used in parallel. I would like some guidance in how to operate with these tools to get the best system state.

Here are my questions:

- There are so many package installing tools when it comes to python: apt-get, pip, easy_install, conda and the python3 version of those. Could somebody explain when one should use the particular tools and the concept of those tools work together? I would even appreciate it if someone could give me a link to an article which actually goes through each of these systems in detail, compares them, and highlights the differences between them.
- Would installing and running python stuff using anaconda take care of the headache of using multiple python package tools?
- If the python packages that anaconda installs are already present in the system how those two coordinate when we use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main similarity between `apt`/`apt-get`, `pip`, `easy_install` and `conda` is that they are package managers; there are more differences between them than there are similarities.

Let's start with easy things first. Never use `easy_install` over `pip`, and the reasons for this are eloquently explained in the various highly upvoted answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/486919. In short, `easy_install` is obsolete and `pip` is always to be preferred.

### `apt`/`apt-get`

You use `apt` or `apt-get` to install at the system/global level Ubuntu packages, including the ones for Python, found in APT repositories. You need to run this command with `sudo`. In the Ubuntu repositories, the names for Python 2 packages are prepended with `python` while that for Python 3 are prepended with `python3`, so it is clear what packages you need to install depending on what version of the Python interpreter you intend to use. Some examples include `python-numpy` and `python3-numpy`.

### `pip`

`pip` stands for ["Pip Installs Packages" or "Pip Installs Python"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)), which is a recursive acronym. As the name suggests, you use `pip` to install Python packages **only**. At the system/global level, you can install `pip` for Python 2 using `sudo apt install python-pip` and for Python 3 using `sudo apt install python3-pip`. In Ubuntu, `pip install` defaults to `pip install --user`. The same happens if you replace `pip` with `pip3`. This means that Python packages are by default installed on a per-user basis and **not** at the system/global level. This is a good thing because there are no good reasons to make Python packages available to all users by default. You can install them globally by running the command with `sudo`, but as I have explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/15003, this is a security risk and should **not** be done.

The best way to manage Python dependencies is to use virtual environments. An example of this is virtualenv, which can be installed using `sudo apt install virtualenv`. I wrote a short answer about this at https://askubuntu.com/a/786625/15003 but there are other very good answers to the question that you can read about.

### `conda`

`conda` is a package manager that also allows you to create virtual environments, so it is somewhat like `pip` + `virtualenv`. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994790/486919, `conda` can also "handle library dependencies outside of the Python packages as well as the Python packages themselves". I personally don't use Anaconda/Conda on my Ubuntu machine since `pip` and `virtualenv` are good enough for my needs, but you should definitely check out `conda`.

Answer (score 2):

> There are so many package installing tools when it comes to python: apt-get, pip, easy_install, conda and the python3 version of those. Could somebody explain when one should use the particular tools and the concept of those tools work together? I would even appreciate it if someone could give me a link to an article which actually goes through each of these systems in detail, compares them, and highlights the differences between them.

## `apt-get`

It is not a Python package manager, it is the package manager *for Ubuntu*. You use it to install Ubuntu software.

As to why it has *Python* packages inside it, Ubuntu packages most Python modules like this: `python-modulename` or `python3-modulename`. These Ubuntu Python modules are outdated. Use `pip` (or `pip3`).

## `pip`

It is the standard Python package manager. When in doubt, *use this*.

## `conda`

It is a Python package manager *plus an environment manager*. That is, it builds you an isolated, fresh Python environment, allowing you to freeze specific modules at a version while not affecting system Python, etc.

> Would installing and running python stuff anaconda take care of the headache of using multiple python package tools?

Firstly, it is *not* a headache. Just

```
$ pip install modulename
```

(or `pip3` for Python 3, since 2 and 3 are hugely incompatible.)

Secondly, `conda` is *yet another package manager for Python*, which has (I think) fewer packages than `pip` and is only good for freezing specific versions of system libraries, Python modules etc.

> If the python packages that anaconda installs are already present in the system how those two coordinate when we use them?

`conda` overwrites already-present packages.