# Why does Amazon give insecure directions for installing awscli?

Tags: apt, python, sudo, pip, aws

Since [pip shouldn't be *used* with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/866949/45156), why does Amazon [give install directions as](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html):

> Install the AWS CLI Using pip
>
> With Python and pip installed, use pip to install the AWS CLI:

...

> Linux, OS X, or Unix
>
> ```
> $ sudo pip install awscli
> ```

instead of the preferred `pip install --user awscli`?  (***After***, presumably, installing `pip` with `sudo`.)

What does @EdWinks know that Amazon doesn't?  Why does Amazon suggest an [insecure install method](https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/45156)?

Comment: This answer you linked to explains what Ask Ubuntu (or rather, @edwinksl) knows that Amazon doesn't. Surely the reason why they recommend this is a matter of opinion (the internet is full of bad advice!) but perhaps they are recommending it on the basis that they expect you to trust their code? (I wouldn't!)

Comment: @Zanna whatever answer someone comes with to guess as to what's in the mind of Amazon, I'll open a ticket with them to ask.  I'm curious now.  I would ***naively*** expect AWS documentation to be better than edwinks.  Clearly they need to pay him $.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the quote in the answer you don't seem to understand:

> In other words, you run arbitrary Python code from the Internet as
>   root.

Now, Amazon employees wrote the CLI for their systems. They know the code. They trust it enough to run it as root. *That* is why they suggest it. Amazon isn't telling you to install random packages using `sudo pip`, they're only talking about their own.

If you want to extrapolate that to every PyPI package, that's your funeral.

Of course, the question still remains: Do *you* trust Amazon enough to run their code as root?