# When I use sudo pip to install software I get the message "the directory... is not owned by the current user"

Tags: software-installation, permissions, sudo, pip

> The directory '`/home/bijay/.cache/pip/http`' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's `-H` flag.

But software get installed. I just want to know what the heck above error means.

For example:-

[image: When I tried to install pandas, it goes like this..]

Comment: The error means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 15):

When you run `sudo` your environment is passed along while the effective user switches to root. Your environment includes that your `~/` or home directory (the value of the environment variable `HOME`) is `/home/bijay`.

`pip` looks for an http cache before downloading packages. Probably for a combination of security, sanity and privacy reasons pip disables the cache so as not to write to a cache directory not owned by the current user. It's just telling you that it did that.

As it hints, using `sudo -H` would set the `HOME` environment variable before executing the command passed to `sudo`, using root's home directory `/root` as `$HOME` instead of your user's. The cache could then be written in `/root/.cache/pip/http` with no errors.

As a sidenote, you probably shouldn't be running `pip` as root anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It pretty much explains. But why running pip as root is not good. Isn't pip just a package manager to install python software/libraries ?

Comment: @Bijayuprety see https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice/802594#802594

Comment: Generally speaking if you want system-wide python packages use your distributions packages instead.

Comment: If you want to install without using root or sudo, simply use the `--no-cache-dir` argument.  The only downside is that it may take a little longer and might use slightly more of your network bandwidth.

Comment: @cowlinator Or you could just ignore the warning because its already disabling the cache. However the warning also tells you what you need to do. If `pip` didn't need root then it'd use the users cache without disabling it.

Answer (score -4):

upgrade pip

```
apt pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Why would that help?