# Pip is not working: ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Tags: python, pip

Running `pip` or `pip3` results with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myuser/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

I had issues with this, and uninstalled pip3, but when i try to install it again using

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

it does install, but then running pip or pip3 i get the same error.

```
#which pip3
/home/myuser/.local/bin/pip3
```

Comment: I have a similar problem after upgrading from pip 9.0.2 to pip-10.0.0. Ubuntu 16.04LTS here.

Comment: You should not upgrade to pip 10 on Ubuntu, because the system version installed through apt is modified in a way not compatible to pip 10. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221 @Dave

Comment: macOS 10.13.4, same problem after upfgrade to pip 10

Comment: Temporary workaround: `python3 -m pip install --user <package>`

Comment: if you have `easy_install` (comes from `python-setuptools` package), you can do `sudo easy_install pip` (or `sudo easy_install3 pip` for python3-only, etc.)

Comment: How did you install Pip originally? It can't have been done through the package manager since that wouldn't result in executables under `~/.local/bin`.

Comment: A simple reboot of the machine may resolve the issue; if you're not going to lose any work then try this before reinstalling anything.

Comment: Can't answer here yet, but I had the same issue and had probably mixed apt and non-apt installs of pip. Purged the bins on my path and installed through apt, problem solved.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5373 
Solution on above link: Before using virtualenv: 
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
And I also uninstalled the latest virtualenv and install 
sudo pip install virtualenv==15.1.0

Comment: I had this happening in a [Docker multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) when I was accidentally trying to run a version of `pip` from one stage that was installed using Python 3 in another stage using Python 2.

Comment: See my answer (use `python -m ...` not `python3 -m ...` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363022/importerror-no-module-named-pip/66956587#66956587

Comment: A `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip python-pip` solved this issue for me on Debian.

Answer (score 252):

After upgrading `pip` (or `pip3`, in this case) if the following occurs:

```
$ ~ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

Force a reinstall of pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Verify install:

```
$ ~ pip3 -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Now `pip3 install <package>` and `pip3 install --user <package>` (for user-level installs) will work correctly.

There should never, ever be any reason you need to run pip in elevated mode.

**For Python 2.7**

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Had same problem on macOS as well, it's a common issue across platforms.

Comment: `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip3'`

Comment: @endolith Okay, now you want to use `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/pip3` – purge that existing directory first, then install from scratch. It's a permissions problem on that directory, but it's better to reset in these circumstances I believe, you can always easily reinstall whatever packages you lose again.
If that doesn't work, nuke your Python 3 install, too, then reboot.

Comment: @BenjaminR How do I nuke all the system python stuff and reinstall it?  I'm sure I've done the wrong thing many times over the years

Comment: @endolith Hi, it depends on what your OS (and distro, if Linux) is. Let me know and I’ll try to point you in the right direction. p.s. We’ve all been in your position more times than most of us like to admit :)

Comment: @BenjaminR Ubuntu, just updated from last LTS to 18.04

Comment: @endolith Okay! See: https://www.fosslinux.com/3534/how-to-completely-uninstall-applications-by-command-line-in-ubuntu.htm

Comment: @endolith Once you've done that, run `which python` / `which python3`. If nothing turns up, reboot your machine, then reinstall python 2/3 using `apt-get install <package name>`. Finally, if you run in to something unexpected, run `find / -iname python*` (you'll probably need `sudo` permissions for these commands). If anything turns up which is a directory with a binary, remove the enclosing directory, then reboot.

Comment: This also works on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Windows 10.

Comment: In my case it was due to python actually resolving to an older version of pip module installed via other means and not via OS apt-get. That older version (8.1) likely lacks the __internal module and once I uninstalled it (python -m pip uninstall pip) the 18.1 pip package installed via apt-get was getting picked up and yes sir it does have an __internal module with the correct permissions etc.

Comment: None of this worked and none of this explains why OP's approach didn't work. Always explain why something doesn't work in the first place. Guessing doesn't explain.

Comment: @foki You are correct, it's not an _answer,_ only a _solution._ It's indeed best to provide the reason. Do you know the answer? I remember looking it up at the time but I've forgotten exactly why it was occurring. If so please tell us or edit my answer? (edited my original reply because I was misreading where you were coming from)

Comment: @BenjaminR The problem occurs because the Python interpreter cannot find `pip._internal` module on `PYTHONPATH`. `pip` is just yet another Python module. To figure out why it cannot be found, one must look at their `PYTHONPATH` and the location of the Python interpreter in their particular case (especially when there are multiple Python installations). Thus, reinstalling `pip` the way you pointed out may or may not solve anything. In sum, to get to a solution valuable to more than one narrow case, we need to understand what we are doing.

Answer (score 60):

I solved this by updating pip via Python, like this:

```
python2 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Comment: `/home/{user}/bldenv/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: yeah this worked for me while the the curl-based answer above did not.

Answer (score 27):

This command also works. It reinstalls `pip`:

```bsh
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: That's the *easiest* answer!

Comment: Worked like a wonder on Ubuntu

Comment: I got `sudo: easy_install: command not found`

Comment: WARNING: The easy_install command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'setuptools.command.easy_install' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py)

Comment: Deprecated because it mentions `easy_`.

Answer (score 9):

Apply these three steps:

1. Go to `/usr/local/bin` by terminal
2. Execute `sudo gedit pip`
3. Change the `from pip._internal import main` into `from pip import main`.

Answer (score 7):

Check if pip is already installed using

```
pip3 -V
```

or

```
pip3 --version
```

If not use this command to install it:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Now you can use

```
python3 -m pip install packageName
```

to install packages using pip.

Comment: this is what OP is already dong.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem as you just now, I found the reason is that you are working without superuser privilege since some internal python packages or modules are installed under superuser privilege.

So you can try by fist entering `sudo su`, then enter your password, and run `pip install`, it might help.

Comment: You should never, ever need to run `pip` with elevated permissions.
Use `--user` flag instead, as in: `pip3 install --user <package>`

Comment: However, when I run without superuser permission, I still got the information like                                                                                                                                                                             
**`pip3 install --user`**
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>\\
    from pip._internal import main**
**ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'**                                                         Could you please help me to figure out why this always happen?

Comment: Ok, I found out why,  if **`from pip._internal import main`** error happen, in my solution, 1) **`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`** 2) **`python3 get-pip.py --user --force-reinstall`**, and then you can run `pip` without superuser permission, **Thank you very much for your advice**, it helps a lot !

Comment: My pleasure! Look, I learned the hard way to be careful about using `sudo` willy-nilly (destroyed my OS multiple times!)

Comment: Hmmm https://askubuntu.com/a/802594/5032

Answer (score 2):

A force re-install of `pip` with `-H` flag worked for me:

```
sudo -H python3.7 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Do not use `sudo` to install pip: https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice

Answer (score 1):

The pip version now is 19.0.1:

```
which pip3
#/home/xxx/.local/bin/pip3
vim /home/xxx/.local/bin/pip3
```

Change `from pip._internal import main` into `from pip import main`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py)