# What does '-H' flag in 'sudo -H' mean?

Tags: command-line, sudo

When I was installing Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04, I came across the command

```
sudo -H pip install -U pip
```

What does `-H` do?

Comment: Related, on running `pip` as root: [Is \`sudo pip install\` still a broken practice?](https://askubuntu.com/q/802544), [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/244641) See also [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv). More broadly related, on `sudo` and `-H`: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006), [What specific bad things happen when gedit is used with sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/632798), [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1186999)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [`man sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sudo.8.html):

```
-H, --set-home
            Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable 
            to the home directory specified by the target user's password 
            database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default 
            behavior.
```

So the `-H` flag makes `sudo` assume `root`'s home directory as `HOME` instead of the current user's home directory. Otherwise some files in the user's home directory would become owned by the root, which may lead to various problems.

Comment: I like this answer, because it mentions the reason why -H is used, which is very important. +1

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy The (weak) reasons were covered in https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18399/60135.